# In Google cloud app engine, how to enable health check for a particular service

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm following the direction describe in a  [google doc about App Engine health check](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks).

According to the doc, it seems that I can enable or disable the health check for a project, but not for a particular service under a project. A project can have multiple services, and I'm wondering if it's possible to control the health check per service, and if yes, how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement

> "I can enable or disable the health check for a project, but not for a
>   particular service under a project."

is incorrect.

Each service has it own `app.yaml` file and you can configure health checks for a particular service via it.

How to do this is explained in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks) you have provided.

Comment: after reading the document again carefully, I think you're right. I'm going to go ahead and test the yaml file option. Thanks.

Comment: @Jake, this is the correct answer and should be marked as such.